# Set initial size for WinForms SplitContainer panel in form designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm working with a WinForms SplitContainer in C# and would like to set an initial size for one of the panels. I know you could set the minimum size, but beyond that I haven't been able to find anything else that would do this, and I want the panels to be resizable to whatever after the initial opening of the window.

Is there a way to do this in the Visual Studio designer (percentage-wise, one panel ~25% and the second taking the rest) without manually coding it in, which would be the obvious solution?

Comment: Move the splitter, works at design-time as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Well I feel silly. Feel free to drop that as an answer, should've thought to check that...

Comment: You don't really need me to post that answer.  Just finish the Q+A you started by sharing what you've learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable within the designer by clicking on the slider and then resizing the panels to the size wanted (courtesy of [HansPassant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990581/set-initial-size-for-winforms-splitcontainer-panel-in-form-designer?noredirect=1#comment88975934_50990581).)

It's not highly precise, so you can't use it to be pixel-perfect, but if pixel-perfect alignment is needed then a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview) control makes more sense to use.

Comment: To make it precise you need to write code, or set `SplitterDistance` based on `Width` of the control at design time.